# How to verify if emails have been received through Google Apps?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

I am new to Google Apps. Our domain has MX records pointing to Google Apps but I have not been receiving some emails in Gmail sent from the server. Where do I check to see if the emails have been received? Is there a log record in Google Apps?

Answer (score 1):

Super administrators of Google Apps for Work, for Education, for Government and Unlimited editions could use the Email Log. See https://support.google.com/a/answer/2604578?hl=en for further details.

By the other hand, the [Google Apps Toolbox](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/) could be used to check several issues. See https://support.google.com/a/answer/2520136?hl=en.

On the end user side, users could use the following Gmail troubleshooter: [An incoming message was delayed or hasn’t arrived](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2935079?hl=en)